# Programmatically Configure VPN on Android

Tags: android

I want to programmatically configure a VPN profile in Android 4.0 device and then connect to it. I tried using [OpenVPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn) but it crashes with an exception `Class Instantiation Exception`. Need some guidance on the process.